# C++ grpc service: how to store custom session data

Tags: c++, grpc

I want to implement a custom authentication logic and when a user authorized using special method I want to set a server side session variable which represents user id to use in other requests. How it's possible to implement the behavior in C++ GRPC server?

Answer (score 0):

Could you clarify what do you need? Do you need customized authentication or authorization? Once TLS handshake completes in gRPC, you can get auth information from AuthContext and then make authorization decision.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Jiangtao's answer which is related to [grpc_server_credentials](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/0263269e41c08f52456c9b4b32584742edbea85d/src/core/lib/security/credentials/credentials.h#L278), you probably also want to take a look at [grpc_auth_metadata_processor](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/include/grpc/grpc_security.h#L602-L615), which is used on servers to process the auth metadata on the request and determine whether the request will be allowed.

From your description, it looks like you are trying to do some additional authorization decisions, besides gRPC authentication. If that's the case, it's not a bad idea to separate your authorization logic apart from gRPC. You could probably do the normal gRPC authentication, get the information from the    AuthContext as Jiangtao mentioned, and then proceed with your custom logic. "Inject" the authorization logic into gRPC stack might not be a good choice here. Please let us know if you have any further questions and we are happy to help! :-)